# LESS mixin with attribute selector and child combinator inheritance

Tags: css, inheritance, css-selectors, less

I'm not sure the title makes sense.  This is the first time I get my hands on LESS (or any CSS preprocessor, actually), and I am trying to modify a website template which uses it.

The original code has

```
.row {
  > *[class*=col-] {
    whatever;
  }
}
```

so by doing

```
#foo {
  .row();
  #bar {
    .col-xs-auto();
  }
}
```

I expect the following CSS :

```
#foo #bar {
  whatever;
}
```

However it doesn't work, which may be obvious since the original code itself doesn't expand all col-* classes (original CSS : `.row > *[class*=col-] { whatever; }`).

How do I make the LESS compiler understand I want `#foo #bar` to "inherit" from `.row > *[class*=col-]` ?

(FWIW, I use `lessc`.)

Comment: *I want to "inherit" from `.row > *[class*=col-]`* -> `&:extend(.row > *[class*=col-]);`. The general recommendation is although to never mix *reusable* code with "final" CSS selectors (look at various `extend` QAs here at SO).

Comment: Thanks, it does work indeed, you should make it an answer.  However I'm not sure I understand the general recommendation, and I couldn't identify seemingly relevant QAs with such discussion about recommendations.  Would you mind providing a particular link ?  I'm interested.